# Web Worker in Angular Library

Tags: angular, performance, web-worker, angular-library

I'm developing an angular library  that perform strong computation operations. So I was interested in implementing the web worker in order to have a better user experience and let the complex operations run on the background.

My problem is that when I run the command `ng g web-worker` with Angular CLI 8, the output is `Web Worker requires a project type of "application".`
Does anyone has suggestion on how to proceed for implementing web worker in my library?

Answer (score 4):

Per se a library should just provide its users with functionalities. It is up to the developer to decide how to use them: in a web page main context, in a web worker or in a server side rendering pipeline. So there is no direct easy way to do what you ask. The correct way would be to create your libraries and then a separate project with for example

`ng new --create-application false workername`

and then configure webpack directly in order to obtain a minified bundle which uses your libraries. If you really want to bundle the webworker inside your library, you may try to inline it ([see](https://medium.com/@dee_bloo/make-multithreading-easier-with-inline-web-workers-a58723428a42)). It also will require you to mess with webpack in order to create the minified result and embed it as a Blob in your bundle.

Have a look at the following links, useful in both cases:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworkify-webpack?activeTab=readme

Comment: Thank you! Actually I found that WebWorkers cannot run on GPU that what I need in order to run my Tensorflow algorithm

Comment: I disagree with a blanket assessment that a library should be unbiased about where it runs, client, server, webworker, or otherwise. My team publishes several private libraries to an internal repository. Many of these modules include code for a web worker, and we know from the start that our apps must implement the webworker code as intended. See my solution for this below.

Answer (score 1):

My team had this same challenge (which lead me to this post), and we figured out a solution that works fairly elegantly.

There are several facets at play:

1. The webworker code must be isolated in a single file with *only* webworker code. We keep our webworker Typescript code isolated in discreet, separate files, one file per worker. No problem here.
2. At *library* build time, the worker Typescript code needs to get compiled. During `ng build` for the library, the Typescript compiler *does* find the webworker typescript files just fine and compiles them. Code like the following works, and results in `custom.worker.ts` getting transpiled to `custom.worker.mjs`.

   ```
    const worker = new Worker(new URL('./custom.worker', import.meta.url), { name: 'CustomWorker', type: 'module' });
   ```

   Sift through your built library's `dist` folder, and you'll find it. It will look like `dist/shared-library-code/esm2020/lib/workers/custom.worker.mjs`. The compiled library Javascript code still has a `new Worker()` expression in it pointing to `./custom.worker`.
3. At *app* build time and run time, the code that instantiates the web worker needs an exact path to the webworker file. But the Webpack process totally rearranges files, bundling some together and changing paths. This is the tricky part.

So, we need some magic to map from the place where the `new Worker()` code *expects* the webworker file to be, to the actual place where the worker code exists. We can do this in 2 setps.

First, create a mapping file in your library. I keep them in a `worker-declarations` folder. These files *must* be named the same as the typescript worker files except with a .js suffix.

```
    // File: .../shared-library-code/worker-declarations/special.worker.js
    export * from "../esm2020/lib/workers/special.worker.mjs";
```

The `export` path is the path to where the worker file exists, relative to the ultimate bundled file in your app's `dist` folder. If you poke around in your app's `dist` folder you'll find it.

Second, update your library's `ng-package.json` to declare your js mapping file as an asset that gets bundled with the library. It looks something like this: (In my case I only copy to the `dist/fesm2020` folder because that's all I need. You can add more lines for `fest2015` or whatever else you need.)

```
   // File: ng-package.json
   "assets": [
       { "input": "./worker-declarations", "glob": "*.worker.js", "output": "fesm2020" }
   ]
```

Hopefully this is enough of a hint to get you to the finish line. Enjoy!

Answer (score -3):

i think you have to add app after `ng generate web-worker` ----> `ng generate web-worker app`!

You can see it in this link https://angular.io/guide/web-worker

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't solve the issue because the error it's not related to which name has the worker. The error is about the project type that in my case it's a library.